# Drawable resources corruption in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I've been attempting to resolve memory issues that cause my app to break when I attempt to create a bitmap with writing and images on it (via canvas / paint). I've been looking into attempting to get the right files repeated in the right places, at the right sizes across all of the various drawables folders.

This involved cutting and pasting a few files in and out, attempting to remove some duplication etc.

However after moving files around I started getting only Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) errors on my Nexus 5. I restored my drawables folders to how they were, and I'm still getting the error no matter what I do. Also an S3 Mini that I use for testing returns FileNotFoundException when I try to access a drawable:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/drawable/"+getApplicationContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(imgId));
```

The path in the error in DDMS looks fine, and no different from when it was working. I really haven't changed anything else and have reverted everything I can, but I seem to have somehow corrupted something to do with my drawables.

I realise there isn't a huge amount to go on here, and I'm not posting my code as I'm not looking for a huge technical solution that dives into my extensive codebase, more just information as to whether this is a known problem / any ideas on what could be causing such a strange issue. I'm using Android Studio.

Comment: Did you try replicating this on a smaller scale? Like creating a new project with all you drawables, for example.

Comment: I have not, but I'm not sure about what that would achieve.

Comment: I can still actually use the image normally, as in I can set it as a src in an imageview, but when I try to get the URI, which previously worked fine, I get the FileNotFoundException.